# Why are the buttons inside the panel not working?

Tags: c#, button, panel

I am working on C# application. Basically my issue is that when I bring up a panel(using panel1.Show() on button click, panel indeed shows up but none of the buttons inside the panel do anything(code is written for the button clicks of those buttons). Part of the code that is working:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (panel1.Visible == false)
        panel1.Show();
    else
        panel1.Hide();
}
```

Now problem is with the button inside(Button 6 is in the panel, set there by designer):

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Hide();
}
```

Clicking on this button(after bringing the panel up) doesn't do anything at all. I have another button which is not working either(bit more complex function of it), however I'm sure I'd be able to resolve it if I understood why the simple one isn't working.
Apologies if solution is out there somewhere, I have honestly tried but couldn't find anything on my own.

Comment: Most likely becaues the event isn't wired up.  Click on `button6`, go to the properties window, click on the lightning bolt icon on top, see if there is a method for the `Click` event.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was exactly the problem. I wasn't really aware that for some buttons I have to do that manually.